# Windows only recognizes half of installed RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios, desktop-computer

I upgraded my RAM capacity from 8 GB to 16 GB of DDR3, but Windows still shows 8 GB. I tested several ways to fix it, but nothing happened. All the videos on YouTube says you must go to msconfig and in the "Boot" tab change maximum memory. But when I went there and checked this option, pressed OK and restarted, it changed back to 0 and the problem is still there. In my BIOS it shows 16 GB of RAM. See the screenshots below:

[image]

In msconfig -> Boot -> Advanced Options:

[image]

Same place after restarting:

[image]

This is what Resmon.exe shows:

[image]

RamMap program:

[image]

The RAM I use is 2x8 GB Corsair XMS3 1600 MHz DDR3 and my motherboard is an MSI 970A-G43. How can I make Windows recognize all the RAM?

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: look into the BIOS for a memory remapping option and toggle it

Comment: i have my answer , and the link in the beginning has it.